# Please help with Olympiad geometry question

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Please help me solve this problem.

Problem 2.27 (BAMO 2012/4). Given a segment AB in the plane, choose on it a point M different from A and B. Two equilateral triangles AMC and BMD in the plane are constructed on the same side of segment AB . The circumcircles of the two triangles intersect in point M and another point N.

(a) Prove that AD and BC pass through point N.

(b) Prove that no matter where one chooses the point M along segment AB, all lines MN
will pass through some fixed point K in the plane.

I have problem in part b. I don't want to use coordinates. Can someone give a hint?

EDIT: Unfortunately this question has been put on hold. I am making this edit to explain myself. I had solved the first part of the problem when I asked here, but I wasn't able to solve the second problem. I don't remember how much progress I had made when I asked here. I didn't think of searching BAMO 2012 before asking here. After the advice from comments, I never asked questions directly from competitions again. This question is old so I can't add my progress anymore, I am sorry I didn't ask properly but I request you to re-open it. I'm one question away from a question ban. If I'm question banned, then I would like to use this edit and thank the mathematical community for answering my questions.

Comment: Well, typing "BAMO $2012/4$" in Google, open the [first archive](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwj4vebV3a_hAhVP3RoKHQNrBikQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhosted.msri.org%2Fbamo%2Fattachments%2Fbamo2012examsol.pdf&usg=AOvVaw34tW-HM_4-PLsh6fAP2NeP). ***Hint***: Have a look at the sixth problem ;)

Comment: @Dr.Mathva thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Blue I don't remember what was my progress when I asked this question. I think that's why it's put on hold.

Comment: @Blue that's fine

Comment: @Random-15: As for getting the problem reopened ... The expectation is the same as when you first posted the question. The community likes to see work you've done. (This information helps people tailor their answers to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know; otherwise, it looks like you're trying to get Math.SE to do your work *for* you.) Since you (reasonably) don't remember what you had done, and the problem already has an accepted answer, you may just have to leave the problem "on hold". (Don't delete it, as this penalizes any answerers.)

Comment: @Blue okay. I hope I don't get a question ban for a very long time. Also, I had just asked for an hint, not for an answer, it was not my intention to get SE to do my work, but I'm very sorry if SE has felt that I have used this platform inappropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Part b:** Draw tangents to circumscribed circles at points $A$ and $B$. These tangents interesect at some point $K$.

It's a known fact that the angle between a tangent and a chord is equal to the corresponding inscribed angle. Because of that:

$$\angle KAB=\angle KBA=60^\circ\tag{1}$$

It follows that triangle $KAB$ is equilateral so:

$$KA=KB\tag{2}$$

Therefore point $K$ has the same power with respect to both circumscribed circles. And because of that, it has to be on the radical axis $MN$. So all lines $MN$ pass through fixed point $K$ defined by (1) and (2).